# Timing function in vanilla js smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a smooth scroll in vanilla js for my one page website which i try to implement without jquery, and I want to add a timing function like cubic bezier. Is there any way to do that in javascript? Here is the code:

```
{
    'use strict';

    let currentY = 0;
    let destination = 0;
    let speed = 40;
    let scroller = null;


    function smoothScroll(id) {

        destination = document.getElementById(id).offsetTop;

        //if the user scrolls down
        if (window.pageYOffset < destination) {

            scroller = setTimeout(function () {
                smoothScroll(id);
            }, 1);

            currentY = currentY + speed;

            if (currentY >= destination) {
                clearTimeout(scroller);
            }

            //if the user scrolls up
        } else {

            scroller = setTimeout(function () {
                smoothScroll(id);
            }, 1);

            currentY = currentY - speed;

            if (currentY <= destination) {
                clearTimeout(scroller);
            }

        }

        window.scroll(0, currentY);

    }

    window.onscroll = function () {
        currentY = this.pageYOffset;
    };


    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".scroll")).forEach(e => {

        e.addEventListener('click', () => {

            smoothScroll(e.href.split('#')[1]);

        });
    });

}
```

And here is a codepen to watch it in action : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYNQym

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use `requestAnimationFrame(fn)` instead of `setTimeout(fn,1)`.

Your animation system is incremental - it says 'am I there yet? if no, go closer; if yes, stop.' This is OK but the only information it gives you about the animation is whether it's finished or not finished.

Easing would be something like 'when it's close to the end, slow down', but you don't know when you are close to the end.

Let's say we want to move from scroll position 100 to scroll position 200, starting at time 0 and ending at time 500. It's a *mapping* of time to position. If it's time 250, we should be at position 150 - they're both halfway. The same thing works for any other time. This is called tweening and it's the most common way to do animation.

Once we're working this way, we can do easing. The easing functions themselves are really simple - [here are all the classic ones](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294).

I can post code if you want but it sounds like you're trying to figure this out yourself, hope this was helpful and good luck.

Comment: Thanks! no dont post code I will check it myself. So all I have to do is to replace the setTimeout with requestanimationframe(also check how it works). The rest of the code is ok ?

Comment: No, you have to write your whole animation a different way. `requestAnimationFrame` will not really change anything but it's how you are 'supposed' to do `setTimeout(fn,1)`.